# What does it mean Garbage Collection?

Tags: account, staking, fees, lamports, close

I wonder what is Garbage Collection?. When an Account no longer has enough Lamports to pay its rent, it will be removed from the network in a process known as Garbage Collection. Someone let you know?.

To deactivate an account how much time is necessary for it?. Someone let you know?.

To avoid deactivate an account I've to transfer there some Solana one time every six months, every year?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [PR](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/33945) that mentions a feature gate to disable rent collection. It also mentions there are no longer rent paying accounts on the network.

> The rent paying accounts on solana are phasing out.
>
> Add a feature gate to disable rent collection. When there are no
> longer any rent paying accounts on the network, we can enable this
> feature.

Answer (score 0):

"Garbage collection" refers to deleting an account on the network. When an account has no more lamports in it, the runtime will "garbage collect" it and reinitialize all of the data. The owner of the account goes back to the system program, and all data is set to empty.

You do not need to worry about an account getting garbage collected through rent because rent does not exist on the network anymore. Those docs need to be updated.